# Batch insertion of spreadsheet cells using gdata-objectivec-client not working

Tags: objective-c, gdata-api, gdata

I am trying to add a batch of cells to a Google Spreadsheet using the GData Objective-C Client as described here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction#Batch_requests.

Here is the code of interest:

```
                      GDataFeedSpreadsheetCell *batchFeed = [GDataFeedSpreadsheetCell spreadsheetCellFeed];
                  NSURL *batchUrl = [[batchFeed batchLink] URL];

                  NSMutableArray *cells = [NSMutableArray array];

                  GDataSpreadsheetCell *cell = [GDataSpreadsheetCell cellWithRow:1 column:1 inputString:@"test" numericValue:nil resultString:nil];

                  GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell *cellEntry = [GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell spreadsheetCellEntryWithCell:cell];
                  [cells addObject:cellEntry];                      
                  [batchFeed setEntries:cells];

                  GDataBatchOperation *op;
                  op = [GDataBatchOperation batchOperationWithType:kGDataBatchOperationInsert];
                  [batchFeed setBatchOperation:op];

                  [service fetchFeedWithBatchFeed:batchFeed forBatchFeedURL:batchUrl completionHandler:nil];
```

It doesn't work.  Clearly, the fetchFeedWithBatchFeed has no reference to my GDataWorksheetEntry object -- so it doesn't surprise me that it isn't working.

What am I leaving out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I mentioned, I believe the problem is that I haven't provided a reference to my GDataEntryWorksheet object.  I suspect that the batch feed somehow has to be derived from this object, but I don't see a way of providing a cells feed from my worksheet entry object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here is the final answer.

You must perform a query before the batch update to get the entries you are going to update.  Sounds obvious in retrospect.  Sure does make for a lot of nested blocks though.

```
                     NSURL *cellsFeedUrl = [[worksheetEntry cellsLink] URL];

                  GDataQuerySpreadsheet *querySpreadsheet = [GDataQuerySpreadsheet spreadsheetQueryWithFeedURL:cellsFeedUrl];
                  [querySpreadsheet setMinimumRow:1];
                  [querySpreadsheet setMaximumRow:1];
                  [querySpreadsheet setMinimumColumn:1];
                  [querySpreadsheet setMaximumColumn:7];
                  [querySpreadsheet setShouldReturnEmpty:TRUE];

                  [service fetchFeedWithQuery:querySpreadsheet completionHandler:
                   ^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

                       // Update one of these cells as a test.
                       GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell *spreadsheetCellEntry = [[feed entries] lastObject];
                       [[spreadsheetCellEntry cell] setInputString:@"test"];

                       NSArray *updatedEntries = [feed entries];
                       NSString *eTag = feed.ETag;

                       // Get worksheet cells feed
                       [service fetchFeedWithURL:cellsFeedUrl completionHandler:
                        ^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

                            NSURL *batchUrl = [[feed batchLink] URL];
                            GDataFeedSpreadsheetCell *batchFeed = [GDataFeedSpreadsheetCell spreadsheetCellFeed];

                            [batchFeed setEntriesWithEntries:updatedEntries];

                            GDataBatchOperation *op;
                            op = [GDataBatchOperation batchOperationWithType:kGDataBatchOperationUpdate];
                            [batchFeed setBatchOperation:op];
                            [batchFeed setETag:eTag];

                            // Perform batch update
                            [service fetchFeedWithBatchFeed:batchFeed forBatchFeedURL:batchUrl
                                          completionHandler:
                             ^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

                                 // no op

                             }];
                        }];
                   }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem and exposed a new issue.

First, the solution.  Once you have a GDataWorksheetEntry, this code will perform a batch operation -- in this case an insert:

```
                      NSURL *cellsFeedUrl = [[worksheetEntry cellsLink] URL];

                  // Get worksheet cells feed
                  [service fetchFeedWithURL:cellsFeedUrl completionHandler:
                   ^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

                       NSURL *batchUrl = [[feed batchLink] URL];
                       GDataFeedSpreadsheetCell *batchFeed = [GDataFeedSpreadsheetCell spreadsheetCellFeed];

                       NSMutableArray *cells = [NSMutableArray array];

                       GDataSpreadsheetCell *cell = [GDataSpreadsheetCell cellWithRow:1 column:1 inputString:@"test" numericValue:nil resultString:nil];

                       GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell *cellEntry = [GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell spreadsheetCellEntryWithCell:cell];

                       static unsigned int staticID = 0;
                       NSString *batchID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"batchID_%u", ++staticID];
                       [cellEntry setBatchIDWithString:batchID];

                       [cells addObject:cellEntry];                      
                       [batchFeed setEntriesWithEntries:cells];

                       GDataBatchOperation *op;
                       op = [GDataBatchOperation batchOperationWithType:kGDataBatchOperationInsert];
                       [batchFeed setBatchOperation:op];

                       [service fetchFeedWithBatchFeed:batchFeed forBatchFeedURL:batchUrl
                                     completionHandler:
                        ^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

                            NSLog(@"FEED ENTRIES: %@",[feed entries]);
                            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);

                        }];
                   }];
```

Unfortunately, when you access the resulting batch feed (done in the logging statement) you will see this:

```
FEED ENTRIES: (
"GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell 0x5fcf510: {v:3.0 title:Error content:Insert not supported on batch. id:batchID_2 batchID:batchID_2 batchStatus:501}"
```

)

So now I need to figure out how to hack around Google's lack of support for batch insertion.

Note that if you change the operation to update you get this:

```
FEED ENTRIES: (
"GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell 0xae73880: {v:3.0 title:Error content:Missing entry id id:batchID_2 batchID:batchID_2 batchStatus:400}"
```

)

The missing entry id is because I created the cell without referencing an existing cell -- so I will focus on trying to provide that reference and providing a batch update call instead of a batch insert call.

Comment: Hi. Did you find the solution for this question?